# Will ZXing overlay affect the scanning area

Tags: uwp, zxing, zxing.net

I'm new to ZXing and didn't find much information about the overlay. I'm curiously will the overlay layer affect the scanning area? Say, the target QR code located in the overlay area, will the zxing recognize it properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay will not affect scanning area, I have similar UI and QR on an edge is recognized fine. However, camera has focus which is often set automatically (or programmatically) on the center. To be able to recognize QR code in your scenario, user will probably have to tap on that area to focus on the image.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to restrict to only recognize the non-overlay area?

Comment: ZXing takes a bitmap for recognizing as I recall. To restrict recognizing to non-overlay area you would need to crop this bitmap to required size and offset, or make MediaCapture to capture bitmap from this area to begin with. [This example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7) can be used as a starting point for cropping bitmap.

Comment: But I think simpler approach would be to programmatically focus on the center where you have your non-overlay area. That way user will have to point this area on QR code, otherwise recognizer will have troubles to read non-focused image.